# Odata filter expression to query for a particular field name in json

Tags: odata

I have the following Odata response

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": ....,
                    "URI": .....,
                    "type": .....
                },
                "SchemaId": "ABC"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": ....,
                    "URI": .....,
                    "type": .....
                },
                "SchemaId": "DEF"
            }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter for all the schemaId. Can anyone help with filter query.

Answer (score 0):

I want to filter for all the schemaId.  -> No idea what you say, but if you want to filter for a SchemaId you have to do it like this:

.../EntitySet$filter=SchemaId eq 'Whateva'

https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).